# Let $R$ be a ring with $10$ elements, show that $R$ is commutative.

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with $10$ elements, show that $R$ is commutative.

$R$ is a ring which contains $10$ elements and doesn't have to include $1$.

Comment: To check: are you thinking about something like the even integers modulo $20$? But non-commutative?

Comment: The question i'm facing doesn't specify what sort of ring it is, only that when one has 10 elements it is commutative.

Comment: This answer might help you - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110271/ring-with-10-elements-is-isomorphic-to-mathbbz-10-mathbbz

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check it out

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825661

Answer (score 3):

The additive group is cyclic, let $g$ be a generator.
Then for arbitrary elements $a=ng$, $b=mg$, we have
$$a\cdot b = ng\cdot mg=nm(g\cdot g)= mn(g\cdot g)=mg\cdot ng=b\cdot a.$$

Comment: And note that $g\cdot g$ defines the multiplication, so the rings of order $10$ can be enumerated quite easily.

Comment: Is it somehow obvious that the underlying abelian group is cyclic?

Comment: @drhab Here is one exaplanation: the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/10 \mathbb{Z}$ which has an additive generator: $2$. Sets of generators are invariant under isomorphism.

Comment: @Rustyn The OP says that the ring has not necessarily an identity. That gives more possibilities.

Comment: @drhab You are right, i didn't see that in the statement of the problem

Comment: @Rustyn Later I realized that there is only one abelian group having exactly $10$ elements. And it is indeed cyclic.